# How can I get parrent div data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have

```
<div class="answers-form"  data-id="1">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label>
           <input value="" type="checkbox" name="answer[]">
       </label>
    </div>
    <span></span>           
</div>
```

I need to check, if input is checked, then get `div`'s `data-id`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to attach a `change` eventlistener to the checkbox, then get the parent using `closest()` and finally the data-attribute using `data()` like :

```
$('[name="answer[]"]').on('change', function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        console.log( $(this).closest('.answers-form').data('id') );
    }
});
```

If you have to check if the the checkbox is checked on submit you could do this inside the submit event like:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ( $('[name="answer[]"]').is(':checked') ) {
        console.log( 'submit' );
    } else {
        console.log( 'Prevent submit' );
        return false;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('[name="answer[]"]').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        console.log($(this).closest('.answers-form').data('id'));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="answers-form" data-id="1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>
       <input value="" type="checkbox" name="answer[]" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <span></span>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, but i forgot to set that i have submit button and this code is a part of form. and after submitting i need to check, which checkbox is not selected and change that div's border color to red.

Comment: Oooooo Great, i forgot about data() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on( "click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if( $( "input=[name='answer[]']" ).is(":checked") === true ) {

        var data_id = $( ".answers-form" ).attr( "data-id" );

    }

});
```

Comment: Added an on submit part, since you described that in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name="answer[]"]').on("change",function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      console.log($(".answers-form").attr("data-id"))
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answers-form"  data-id="1">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label>
           <input value="" type="checkbox" name="answer[]">
       </label>
    </div>
    <span></span>           
</div>
```